# Using regular expression to get values from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string in my database...

```
"[{:@error=>"Invalid information was sent: ''.  Check the attribute for correct input value."}, {:@error=>"Invalid phone number: "}, {:@error=>"Invalid address: "}]"
```

I would like to parse it out so only the strings inside `@error=>` appears.

Something similar to this

- "Invalid information was sent: ''.  Check the attribute for correct input value."
- "Invalid phone number: "
- "Invalid address: "

From a previous example I tried to use something like this...

```
string.scan(/'([^']+)'/).flatten.map{ |msg| msg.gsub(/(\.|\s+)/, ' ').strip }
```

But that returned an empty array.

Comment: You don't need regexes for this. Try `errors = [{:@error=>"Invalid information was sent: ''.  Check the attribute for correct input value."}, {:@error=>"Invalid phone number: "}, {:@error=>"Invalid address: "}]` and then `errors.map! {|e| e[:@error]}` after this errors will be an array containing just the messages.

Comment: That isn't a string, it's an array. Your previous question used a YAML string. There are answers given to that question that show how to extract information from the parsed YAML which directly apply to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
@error=>"(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rA3oV2/1)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [12-91] `Invalid information was sent: ''.  Check the attribute for correct input value.`
MATCH 2
1.  [106-128]   `Invalid phone number: `
MATCH 3
1.  [143-160]   `Invalid address: `
```